# How to change the state of a sibling component in ReactJS for a Master/Slave checkbox system?

Tags: reactjs

I'm curious how to implement a Master/Slave checkbox system. The approach I am currently taking is to have an owner/ownee (parent/child) relationship between the Master/Slave checkboxes. However, I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish this in React if the checkboxes were siblings instead. I see here in the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) that it says to use your own global event system. Can someone please explain/show me an example of what they mean by this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my Backbone+React application I use backbone events when I do not have any other options to communicate states between the components. I am pretty sure you can find other minimal event libraries or build your own to communicate events if you need to.

Below is an example code from the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/2239/ ,I have supplied for your scenario.

From the 'MasterCheckbox' component's onChange event I trigger a global application wide 'checkbox:clicked' event on the event object that's accessible to other components/views.

```
//Global event object
window.App = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

//MasterCheckbox component's change handler
handleChange: function () {
  this.setState({checked: this.refs.master.getDOMNode().checked});
  App.trigger('checkbox:clicked', this.refs.master.getDOMNode().checked);
}
```

Then on the 'SlaveCheckbox' component I subscribe to that event and change the state of the
'SlaveCheckbox' component

```
componentDidMount: function(){
     App.on('checkbox:clicked', function(state){this.setState({checked: state}) }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but im really trying to see if everything can be done in React, without any external libraries.

Comment: Ive accomplished how to do this only using React, I will post my code shortly.

Comment: Well maybe you should have said in the question that you wanted to solve the problem only using React. The event system is something you can come up on our own without depending on an event library. Plus the problem is easily solvable by having parent component that manages the state for the child components which I assume is what you have done. You asked for an example of an event based solution and that is what the answer refers to.

Comment: I DID SAY THAT: "However, I'm curious if there's a way to accomplish this in React if the checkboxes were siblings instead." - In React, doesn't mean using another library with React, it means, INSIDE OF THE CAPABILITIES OF REACT.

Comment: "I see here in the docs that it says to use your own global event system. Can someone please explain/show me an example of what they mean by this?" and that's what I exactly did. And if you had read the answer I have said that you can build your own minimal event system does not have to be an external library.

Comment: @evkline you can post your code in an answer, and then accept it.  It might help other people in the future :-)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand just posted an answer that might give you an example.

Comment: Pretty sure I saw "in Reactjs" in the **title**

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the two checkboxes into their own component to make a MasterSlaveComponent. Wasn't sure of the exact functionality you would want, but here is an example where turning on Master also turns on Slave.

```
var MasterSlaveCheckbox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        master: false,
        slave: false
      }
    },

    handleMasterChange: function() {
      var newMasterState = !this.state.master;

      if(newMasterState) {
        this.setState({master: true, slave: true});
      } else {
        this.setState({master: false});
      }
    },

    handleSlaveChange: function() {
      this.setState({slave: !this.state.slave});
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.master} onChange={this.handleMasterChange} />
              Master
            </div>

            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.slave} onChange={this.handleSlaveChange}  />
              Slave
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crob611/z6ozz62a/1/